# javascript function call inside same function

Tags: javascript, function, onclick, onclicklistener

i wanna ask why i cannot execute the onclick function inside the same function?  is there any syntax errors in button onclick?

PS: delete is a string , and ID is variable that install an Client ID.

```
<td> <button id='delete' onclick='action("delete",ID)'> </button> </td>
```

Comment: Are you sure ID is set at the time of clicking? In addition, can you try adding text to the button and checking if it works like that? Currently, it's implied that the button is somehow styled via CSS, and if this is the case can you share the styling code?

Comment: i want to make up a table and dynamically delete the record followed by ID

Comment: i want to ask if i want to pass null to variable place how can i make it correct

Answer (score 0):

You can do your functionality via below way:-

```
// set your ID in below line as id="ID"
<button id="ID" onClick="action(this.id)"></button>

<script type="text/javascript">
function action(clickeId)
{
    alert(clickeId);
}
</script>
```

Hope it will help you :)

Comment: how come i cannot pass the ID to ajax data